# how to create dynamic tablerow with two textview and imageview which has to be populated by sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to add a TextView and an ImageView in the table row of a TableLayout by using a SQLite database.

Please let me know about this code.
I have searched a lot, but I'm not able to get the proper solution.

Comment: `I have searched a lot, but I'm not able to get the proper solution.` I highly doubt you searched at all. There's a bazillion tutorials about achieving a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps easy to achieve your output

1) Retrieve all data from database and store in List.

2) Refer following example
http://www.android-examples.com/android-simple-recyclerview-example-tutorial/

3) Change (above example's recyclerview_items.xml) EditText instead of Texview.

Comment: i want text-view and image-view in the same row by using SQL-lite database.